The ready event for socket in http server node.js
Lately I've been looking at the node.js sources and something has interested me.
Code:
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.end("hello");
});

server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Runing on port 3000");
});

server.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("connection received, let's listen event 'ready'");
  socket.on('ready', (...args) => console.log("ready", args));
})

The ready event in this code will never be listened to. What am I doing wrong or what is missing?

Node.js doc says:

Event: 'ready'
Emitted when a socket is ready to be used.


next sentence is Triggered immediately after 'connect' perhaps you're trying to listen too late?

@JaromandaX it can't be late 'ready' is just alias for 'connect'.

Yeah, I didn't explain it very well

@JaromandaX afterConnect is not called, that must emit 2 events ready and connect. Why afterConnect isn't called is a question.
